# Localhost issue in Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache2, localhost

I was trying to run a php file on my webpage however I have some issues with localhost.
I have already installed apache2 and php5 (re-installed them to be sure) and I have created a `phpinfo.php` file under `/var/www/` in order to check my localhost containing a single line of code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
. However I get the following error message when I try to access `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpinfo.php on this server.
```

When I'm trying to run `sudo service apache2 restart` I get the following response:

> - Restarting web server apache2 AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/http] does not exist AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably
>     determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.
>     Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

What's the problem with localhost?

Moreover I have one more question. I have a project (webpage) under a folder `project`, that contains `.php` and `.css` files. How can I make the webpage appear in my web browser using localhost?

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: And also your Apache `error.log`. Everything else is guessing.

Comment: Where is `.htaccess` located? Under `/var/www/` ?

Comment: Also check the permissions on the web folders.  Apache needs to have at least read access to any file you want it to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu recently changed the http folder to `/var/www/html`. Maybe you are running centOS that perhaps did the something similar.

> Restarting web server apache2 AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [**/var/www/http**] does not exist

So put your files you want to serve in `/var/www/http` instead. And create the folder if it does not exist.

Comment: What doesn't work? When you restart the server, what does it say?

Comment: I'm running `sudo cp -r project /http/`
And I get the same response when I restart the server

Comment: That's supposed to be `/var/www/http`, or alternatively `http` if you're in that folder.

Comment: if you mean to run `cp -r project http`  
i get `cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'http' with directory 'project' `

Comment: Show us the output of `ls -la /var/www` please.

Comment: total 32  
`drwxr-xr-x  5 george root 4096 Feb  3 01:21`  
`drwxr-xr-x 14 root         root         4096 Feb  3 01:47 ..`  

`drwxr-xr-x  4 root         root         4096 Feb  3 01:25 html`

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 george george   15 Mar  9  2014 http -> comic-lab/http/`

`drwxrwxr-x  7 george george 4096 Feb  3 01:21 .http`

`-rw-r--r--  1 george root           20 Feb  3 00:17 phpinfo.php`

`-rw-r--r--  1 george george   19 Feb  3 00:17 phpinfo.php~`

`drwxrwxr-x  7 george george 4096 Feb  3 00:39 project`

Comment: You have a dead symlink in there. Do `sudo rm http` to get rid of it. Then do `sudo mkdir http`.

Comment: I added `ServerName localhost` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` in order to fix the problem

Comment: I can now see the `project` in localhost, however when I click on the folder, a blank page appears. Under `project` I have the `index.php`. 
How can I access `index.php` and make it appear on my web browser?

Comment: You should ask a new question. And adding Servername to your config file had nothing to do with your problem.